# How to get maximum value based on another series in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large Data frame, in that  a column called **currency** and **amount_in_euros**, Currency column contains data like EUR, GBR etc., and amount_in_euros contains float value. I want to compute sum of each currency(EUR, GBR etc.,) and put maximum value of currency in new series. **I have to compute this operation for each customer**. How to achieve this in pandas.

Input:

```
Customer  currency   amount_in_euros
1           EUR      10
1           GBR      6
1           GBR      18
1           EUR      2
1           EUR      3
2           IND      12 
.
.
.
```

Output:

```
Customer  currency   amount_in_euros   max
1           EUR      10                GBR
1           GBR      6                 GBR
1           GBR      18                GBR
1           EUR      2                 GBR
1           EUR      3                 GBR 
2           IND      12                IND
. 
. 
.
```

so far I tried,

```
df=pd.read_csv('analysis.csv')
res=pd.DataFrame()
for u,v in df.groupby(['Customer']):
   temp= v[['currency','amount_in_euros']].groupby(['currency'])['amount_in_euros'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('amount_in_euros',ascending=False)
   v['max']=temp['currency'].iloc[0]
   res=res.append(v)
```

My above code works fine for me, but due to append operation it takes a long time. please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

- first aggregate `sum` by `Customer` and `currency`
- sort by columns by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
- [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for rows with `max`
- create `Series` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
- last create new column by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Customer', 'currency'], as_index=False)['amount_in_euros'].sum()
s = (df1.sort_values(['Customer','amount_in_euros'])
        .drop_duplicates('Customer', keep='last')
        .set_index('Customer')['currency'])

df['max'] = df['Customer'].map(s)
print (df)
   Customer currency  amount_in_euros  max
0         1      EUR               10  GBR
1         1      GBR                6  GBR
2         1      GBR               18  GBR
3         1      EUR                2  GBR
4         1      EUR                3  GBR
5         2      IND               12  IND
```

EDIT:

Similar solution for first, second, third values in new columns:

```
print (df)
   Customer currency  amount_in_euros
0         1      EUR               10
1         1      GBR                6
2         1      GBR               18
3         1      EUR                2
4         1      USD                1
5         1      USD                2
6         1      EUR                3
7         2      IND               12
8         2      USD                2

df1 = df.groupby(['Customer', 'currency'], as_index=False)['amount_in_euros'].sum()
df2 = df1.sort_values(['Customer','amount_in_euros'])
df2 = (df2.set_index(['Customer', 
                      df2.groupby(['Customer']).cumcount(ascending=False)])['currency']
          .unstack()
          .add_prefix('max_'))

print (df2)
         max_0 max_1 max_2
Customer                  
1          GBR   EUR   USD
2          IND   USD  None

df = df.join(df2, on='Customer')
```

---

```
print (df)
   Customer currency  amount_in_euros max_0 max_1 max_2
0         1      EUR               10   GBR   EUR   USD
1         1      GBR                6   GBR   EUR   USD
2         1      GBR               18   GBR   EUR   USD
3         1      EUR                2   GBR   EUR   USD
4         1      USD                1   GBR   EUR   USD
5         1      USD                2   GBR   EUR   USD
6         1      EUR                3   GBR   EUR   USD
7         2      IND               12   IND   USD  None
8         2      USD                2   IND   USD  None
```

Comment: @jezrael- works fine :-). Thanks a lot. Can I get second largest value in another series using similar fashion.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - there is always second max value?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - Added solution for it.